# How Do I Share File Descriptors Between Processes in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

I use Jane Street async in my OCaml code.  I start up a child process in the standard way like this:

```
Process.create ~prog ~args
```

I understand that does your basic fork/exec on a Unixy machine.  I'd like to write to the same stderr in both processes.  Assuming this is a good idea (I realize it may not be), how do I pass the file descriptor of the parent's stderr to the child?

Answer (score 1):

In a standard Unix fork/exec file descriptors are passed through automatically unless you take action (usually between fork and exec) to prevent it. So if `Process.create` does a standard fork/exec there's nothing to do (other than flushing buffers beforehand).

Conversely, if `Process.create` closes and/or reassigns file descriptors there's not much you can do. In that case you might call fork and exec more directly yourself.